# when I use \nuxt\strapi\ nuxt/apollo,it always told Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

Tags: nuxt.js

when I use \nuxt\strapi\  nuxt/apollo,it always told Cannot read property 'content' of undefined.
if I refresh the page it works!

why?

how can I do for it?

here is my codes

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="about-content">
      <div id="zwqkl" v-html="$md.render(aboutuses[0].content)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import aboutusQuery from '~/apollo/queries/aboutus/aboutus'

export default {
  name: 'about-us',
  data() {
    return {
      aboutuses: []
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    aboutuses: {
      query: aboutusQuery
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers your question: [Nuxt JS Apollo data only available after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213290/nuxt-js-apollo-data-only-available-after-page-refresh/60016982#comment114090634_60016982)

The key is to use the "$loadingKey" property. I updated your code accordingly.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="!loading" class="about-content">
      <div id="zwqkl" v-html="$md.render(aboutuses[0].content)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import aboutusQuery from '~/apollo/queries/aboutus/aboutus'

export default {
  name: 'about-us',
  data() {
    return {
      loading: 0,
      aboutuses: []
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    $loadingKey: 'loading',
    aboutuses: {
      query: aboutusQuery
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to prefetch your result?

```
apollo: {
  prefetch: true,
  aboutuses: {
    query: aboutusQuery
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this,it did't work either.I think this should be a life cycle issue with NUXT rendering.Do u have anyother solutions?