# Nuxt apollo TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

I am using NuxtJS Vue-apollo to get GraphQL data from WordPress with CPTs.

There are several pages in NuxtJS which respectively lists `posts`, `CPT1` and `CPT2`. I can display posts from all just fine, if I reload the page. However if i go from the page which lists `posts` to `CPT1` or any other combination i get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined`.

The first page can list the posts even if I go back, while all others get the error. The queries looks like this:

```
query queryPosts {
  posts {
    nodes {
      id
      title
      modified
      date
      slug
      uri
      featuredImage {
        node {
          id
          sourceUrl(size: THUMBNAIL)
          altText
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And:

```
query queryCPT1 {
cpt1 {
    nodes {
      id
      title(format: RENDERED)
      uri
      problemer { <- this is an ACF field
        cardTitle
        cardImage {
          id
          sourceUrl(size: LARGE)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried displaying the JSON data raw on the page, and that works. But if i try to specify anything inside the result JSON i get the error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: any difference to earlier, already resolved problems like https://stackoverflow.com/a/60016982/6124657 ?

Comment: @xadm thank you! I tough I had tried this, but did not implement it correctly.